# Why ConfigureAwait(true) does not work on unit tests?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, synchronizationcontext

By default, a unit test does not capture the `SynchronizationContext` in which it is run, so if you write something like:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task AwaitThreadSwitch()
{
    WriteThread();
    await Do();
    WriteThread();
}

private Task Do()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        WriteThread();
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    });
}

private void WriteThread()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"CURRENT THREAD: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

You obtain the following output:

```
CURRENT THREAD: 8
CURRENT THREAD: 6
CURRENT THREAD: 6
```

And that's ok: once the `await` is called and returns, the flow does not return to the original Thread.

Now, if I write the test method this way:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task AwaitThreadSwitch()
{
    WriteThread();
    await Do().ConfigureAwait(true);  // <-- note this change
    WriteThread();
}
```

I would expect:

```
CURRENT THREAD: 8
CURRENT THREAD: 6
CURRENT THREAD: 8 // <-- back to the main Thread
```

Instead, I get the same result of the first test.

Why isn't the execution marshalled back to the main Thread of the test method?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` has nothing to do with threads. Nothing at all. Any thread in the pool can execute any task, always. Async code can resume after an `await` on any thread, always. This is by far the #1 misconception about the `Task` API. I don't know where it came from.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson: I would disagree with your characterization. It is true that as an abstraction, a `SynchronizationContext` doesn't necessarily have to correspond exactly to threads. But that doesn't mean it literally has _"nothing at all"_ to do with them. In the common case of Winforms or WPF, the context is in fact tied to a specific thread, an `await` _will_ in fact always resume on that thread (unless otherwise directed), and it is in fact useful to think about the thread the code is executing on. Maybe the "misconception" came from the fact that it's not actually one.

Comment: Supporting @PeterDuniho as this statement is 100% correct and bonus points for the way it is written.
For anyone wondering, I wrote a longer article about the many misconceptions of ConfigureAwait() here: https://github.com/awaescher/ObviousAwait

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand why the test doesn't marshal back to the main thread in your first example. It's not because somewhere something has implicitly set `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Rather, it's because *there is no synchronization context*.

Your two tests are effectively identical. Calling `ConfigureAwait(true)` isn't different from not calling it at all. It's just that there's no context to come back to, and the default synchronization context behavior is to just continue on in the same thread.

So, that's what you see in both tests. Because both tests really do the same thing.

Comment: But if I set a `SynchronizationContext` for my unit test, they will not be the same any more, am I right?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus: no, you're mistaken. Your unit tests _are_ in fact identical. Even if you set a `SynchronizationContext`. For them to be different, one would have to call `ConfigureAwait(false)`, not `ConfigureAwait(true)`.

Comment: In fact `await Do()` is exactly the same as `await Do().ConfigureAwait(true)`. This is unfortunate in terms of clarity but it's understandable why Microsoft made it this way if you dig deeper (I shared a deep dive "Obvious Await" on that in a comment to the question above).
However I would expect NUnit to behave differently when `await Do().ConfigureAwait(false)` is used versus `await Do().ConfigureAwait(true)` but it seems NUnit just loses its `SynchronizationContext` after the first `await` which eliminates the destinction of `ConfigureAwait(true/false)`.